# Conformal mapping of nonsimply connected domains

Tags: complex-analysis, transformation, conformal-geometry

The question asks: Map the complement of the arc $|z|=1$, $y\geq 0$ on the outside of the unit circle so that the points at $\infty$ correspond to each other. How would you construct such conformal map? I think you need to map the arc to part of real/imaginary axis then use square root function. How would you construct this map in details though?

Thanks

Comment: Could you describe the space a little more precisely? The space your description suggests to me is not simply connected.

Comment: @Travis ... nor is the compplement of the unit disk simply connected.

Comment: Typo, I meant NON-simply connected

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I interpreted the description of the region to mean $\mathbb{C}$ less the upper unit semicircle, but looking at the answer the region in question seems to be the upper half-plane less that semicircle.

Comment: @amathnerd You should be able to edit your the subject line, e.g., the add the missing prefix "non-$, in this case I did it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First map $z\mapsto \frac1{z+1}$ to bring $\infty$ to $0$ (because we want to keep an eye on the point at $\infty$). At the same instance, this turns the arc to a half line, ending in $\frac12$. Taking the square root centered at its end point, i.e. applying $z\mapsto \sqrt{x-\frac12}$, we obtain a half plane. You sure know how to turn this into the unit disk. Now watch where $\infty$ has gone in this process and apply a reciprocal map that brings it back to $\infty$. Now you already have a complement of *some* disk, and after scling and translation it becomes the unit disk.

Comment: Thanks for your dedicated answer. I just got this problem by first using the transformation $T=\frac{z+1}{z-1}$ turn the upper disk into a line, then do some transformation to get the upper half plane. Next, change it to unit disk and invert it.

Comment: but the problem is my way does not preserve $\infty $