# Map the complement of the arc $|z|=1$, $Imz\geq0$, on the outside of the unit circle so that points at $\infty$ correspond to each other.

Tags: complex-analysis

Question: Map the complement of the arc $|z|=1$, $\operatorname{Im}z\geq0$, on the outside of the unit circle so that points at $\infty$ correspond to each other.

My attempt: Let $\Omega$ be the region we start with above.

$z_1\mapsto\frac{z_1+1}{z_1-1}$ takes $\Omega$ to the upper half plane.
$z_2\mapsto\sqrt{z_2}$ takes the upper half plane to the right upper half plane.
$z_3\mapsto\frac{z_3-1}{z_3+1}$ takes the right upper half plane to the upper unit circle.

$z_4\mapsto z_4^2%$ takes the upper unit circle to the unit circle.

$z_5\mapsto\frac{1}{z_5}$ takes the unit circle to the outside of the unit circle.

Finally, composing them, $z_5z_4z_3z_2z_1z=\frac{1}{\Bigg(\frac{\sqrt{\frac{z+1}{z-1}}-1}{\sqrt{\frac{z+1}{z-1}+1}}\Bigg)^2}$

I was wondering if I am correct, or if there is a glaring mistake somewhere.  Moreover, how do I confirm that the points at $\infty$ correspond to each other?  Do I need to consider the cross product?  Any help is greatly appreciated!  Thank you.

I did notice that this problem is asked here:
[Conformal mapping of nonsimply connected domains](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/970237/conformal-mapping-of-nonsimply-connected-domains)
but I am just wondering whether or not my map would preserve the points at $\infty$, or if there is something more...

Comment: I do not understand why your first step gives the upper half plane. Are you sure about this?

Comment: I'm not, but I always thought that was a "common map"

Comment: I do not understand why your fourth step gives the unit circle. Are you sure about this?

Comment: I believe so... I tried constructing this using "common maps", but I'm beginning to think that some of the maps that I thought were "common" may be wrong..

Comment: Forget about common. A map is a tool, and it is not inherently wrong. But it may be wrong for a particular task. By the way, I clicked your link above to question 970237. Notice there was some confusion there about what exactly $\Omega$ is. (This is an English difficulty, not a mathematical one.)

Comment: @311411 So, based on the comment on the linked problem, if I take the map $x\mapsto\sqrt{x-\frac{1}{2}}$ (after the previous transformations that they've made, then square the resulting map (taking it to the unit disk), then take $z\mapsto\frac{1}{z}$ to go "back to infinity", would that suffice?  I do appreciate your input!

Comment: By the points at $\infty$ do you mean only on the real axis $\infty$ and $-\infty$ or complex points at an angle in the upper half plane $(a+ ib)*\infty$ ?
Checking on the $+1$ under the square root in the equation is this correct: $f(z) = \frac{1 + \frac{z + 1}{z - 1}}{\left(\sqrt{\frac{z + 1}{z - 1}} - 1\right)^{2}}$

Comment: @arthur I always took the "point at infinity" here to be considered on the positive imaginary axis.  How did you dermine that composition, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: I put your equation $z_5z_4z_3z_2z_1z=\frac{1}{\Bigg(\frac{\sqrt{\frac{z+1}{z-1}}-1}{\sqrt{\frac{z+1}{z-1}+1}}\Bigg)^2}$ into octave's symbolic system which is an interface to SymPy then generated a latex output.

Comment: @arthur But that is the issue - how can we guarentee that map does what we want?  For instance, I believe I have some mistakes based on 311411's comments.

Comment: I was setting up equations to look at it numerically then realized I wasn't sure what the points at infinity meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\Omega$ be the complex plane with the arc $\{e^{it}:t \in [0,\pi]\}$ removed.

The following steps, when composed, map $\Omega$ onto $\mathbb{C}\setminus\overline{\mathbb{D}}$, as desired.

0. The starting point is $\Omega$.
1. Apply $T_1: z\mapsto \frac{az+b}{cz+d}=\frac{z+1}{z-1}.$
2. Apply $T_2: z\mapsto \sqrt{z}=(re^{i\theta})^{\frac{1}{2}}$,   $\quad\{-\frac{\pi}{2}<\theta<\frac{3\pi}{2}\}.$
3. Apply $T_3:z \mapsto e^{i\pi/4}z$.
4. Apply $T_4: z\mapsto \frac{az+b}{cz+d}=\frac{z-e^{i\pi/4}}{z-e^{-i\pi/4}}.$
5. Apply $T_5: z\mapsto \frac{az+b}{cz+d}=\frac{1}{z}.$

The answer given by Hagen von Eitzen during the year '14 is not very different. He began like this:

0. The starting point is $\Omega$.
1. Apply $H_1: z\mapsto \frac{az+b}{cz+d}=\frac{1}{z+1}.$
2. Apply $H_2:z \mapsto z-\frac{1}{2}$.
3. Apply a branch of square root...
   from there, the finish is similar to the one above with the $T_j.$

You should double check that the point at infinity returns back home after its journey around $\overline{\mathbb{C}}.$

Comment: In the step 4, is there some typo? The determinant seems to be 0.

Comment: i think you are right

Comment: Then we have $T_4(\infty) = 1,T_4(1)=-i,T_4(0)=-1$, meaning the real axis is mapped to the unit circle and in particular the upper half plane is mapped to the interior. So I think we need something more? I checked Hagen von Eitzen's answer. If we adopt something from his, we can let $T_4: z\mapsto \frac{1}{z-e^{i \pi /4}}$ and then do a translation and a scaling.

Comment: now I think it works. Thank you for pointing out my error, cheers. @YuqiaoHuang